# strange R subsetting

Tags: r, subset

I have a vector

```
data<-tibble(a=c(30,31,33,35,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,55,56,58,64),
b=NA)
```

I now want to change the values in column b when it matches an input in a.

```
data[data$a==38,"b"]<-1
```

Works fine when I use just one condition. But if i want to change 2 columns at once i gets strange

```
data[data$a==c(30,31),"b"]<-1 #works
data[data$a==c(35,36),"b"]<-1 #not
data[data$a==c(55,56),"b"]<-1 #works
```

why does `data$a==c(30,31)` & `data$a==c(55,56)` return 2xTRUE and `data$a==c(35,36)` all false? I don´t see the difference.

Comment: Try `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: Thank you. This fixes the code. But what is sthe reason that my former approach dont work?

Comment: `==` test for equality with **each** element of the vector on the right hand side. You want equality with *any* of the elements of the vector on the right hand side, for which you use `%in%`

Comment: Also, the recycling gets weird when you have multiple elements on the left hand side, especially when the lengths of the two vectors are not equal. Surely you got some sort of warning along the lines of `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: Compare `1 == 1:3` with `1:2 == 1:3` with `1:3 == 1:3`. It goes element-wise, recycling as needed

Comment: Thank you very much!